# Incorrect query special validation - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a special validation:

> When I'am creating a new message, I must assign values "from_value",
> "to_value" and select a message type (1 to 12) these values must not
> intercept with old values **of the same type**

example:
[image]

[image]

I made this validation in **AppServiceProvider.php** in

> public function boot()

```
    Validator::extend('range_not_repeated',
        function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $data = $validator->getData();

            $existsoldranges = MailMessage::where('type', '=' ,$data['type'])
                ->where(function ($query) use ($data) {
                    $query->where('from_value', '<=', $data['to_value'])
                        ->where('to_value', '>=', $data['from_value']);
                })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($data) {
                    $query->where('from_value', '<=', $data['to_value']);
                    $query->where('to_value', '>=', $data['to_value']);
                })->count();
            return $existsoldranges == 0;
       });
```

but I get the validation error **with all types of messages, my validation only verify the range for all types**

[image]

please I need help with this

Comment: what is the logic or reason for this `$query->where('from_value', '<=', $data['to_value']); $query->where('to_value', '>=', $data['to_value']);`

Comment: @bhucho is for detect a cross value with my database

Comment: If you could elaborate more about the need of orWhere(), then I can solve the missing riddle to your problem

Comment: @bhucho is for detect a cross value with database too, I need the ranges not to intersect within others ranges of the same type